# Does .call in javascript bind itself to the calling object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I've seen many examples that look like this:

```
function MyThing() {
   SomeObj.call(this);
}
```

I understand that .call is calling SomeObj with the context of MyThing's `this`. What I don't understand is does this also bind SomeObj's prototype to MyThing?

The way I've actually seen this implemented is through the use of Streams in Node.

```
util.inherits(MyStream, Transform);

function MyStream() {
    Transform.call(this);
}

MyStream.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {}

var test = new MyStream();
```

Why must we call `Transform.call(this)`? Does this basically take the place of having to first create a `new Transform()` and then using util.inherits?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: Also, from the Transform Node doc: `In classes that extend the Transform class, make sure to call the constructor so that the buffering settings can be properly initialized.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; you still need to call `util.inherits()`.

The point of calling the superconstructor is exactly that – to run any logic in that constructor, initializing the instance base class.
It has nothing to do with the prototype, although the superconstructor is very likely to assume that `this` inherits its prototype.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHH. Derp. So When I create a new MyStream, because it is an inherited class of Transform, I also want to make sure I call the Transform constructor, just as if I had init'd a new Transform directly. Thank you.

Comment: [This blog post may help you better understand `this`.](http://blog.ponyfoo.com/2013/12/04/where-does-this-keyword-come-from)

Comment: [This blog post may help you better understand inheritance](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/).